# How can I get the text of editText?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

Im trying to make a random interger with hashcode of a particular String and I have to get the String from the editText. Below is a code I tried.

```
findViewById<View>(R.id.goButton).setOnClickListener{
        val intent = Intent(this, Activity2::class.java)
        intent.putIntegerArrayListExtra("result", 
  ArrayList(getNumbersFromHash(editText.getText().toString())))
 
        startActivity(intent)
    }
```

A List made of random integers are tossed to **Activity2**. The point is I have to get the text from the editText but **editText.getText().toString()** doesn't work. I have checked the id of the editText and there was no problem. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Can you show where you assign the `editText` property or variable with `findViewById`?

Comment: Oh thanks, there was a little mistake at the binding part. When I use findViewById of EditText the type should be <TextView> is it right?

Comment: `<TextView>` or `<EditText>` should do it. EditText is more specific than Textview and would allow you some additional commands specific to EditText, but you might not need those.

Comment: pls use findViewById<EditText> for edit text.